# Fatal Error com write.csv no R

Tags: r, csv, osx

Quando eu abro um arquivo csv utilizando o read_csv e depois tento salvá-lo na pasta de origem utilizando o mesmo nome, o R acusa Fatal Error e é encerrado.

Uso o R 4.1.1 no MacOS Big Sur 11.5.2.

Comment: Consegue dar mais informações sobre o código? É sempre bom colocar um trecho de código que você julgue necessário para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 6):

Felizmente, tenho a mesma configuração de software aqui e pude reproduzir o erro. De fato, ao ler um arquivo csv com a função `readr::read_csv` e tentar sobrescrever este mesmo arquivo, o RStudio acusa um crash:

```r
library(readr)

dados <- read_csv("penguins.csv")
write.csv(dados, file = "penguins.csv")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma solução para isso é adicionar o argumento `lazy = TRUE` ao ler os dados. Assim, o problema está resolvido.

```r
library(readr)

dados <- read_csv("penguins.csv", lazy = TRUE)
write.csv(dados, file = "penguins.csv")
```

Isto está melhor explicado no help da função `readr::read_csv`:

> Read values lazily? By default the file is initially only indexed and the values are read lazily when accessed. Lazy reading is useful interactively, particularly if you are only interested in a subset of the full dataset. Note, if you later write to the same file you read from you need to set lazy = FALSE. On Windows the file will be locked and on other systems the memory map will become invalid.

Em uma tradução livre,

> Ler valores de maneira *lazy*^? Por padrão, o arquivo é apenas indexado e os valores são lidos apenas quando acessados. A leitura *lazy* é útil interativamente, principalmente se você estiver interessado apenas em um subconjunto do conjunto de dados completo. Observe que, se posteriormente você gravar no mesmo arquivo que leu, será necessário definir `lazy = FALSE`. No Windows, o arquivo será bloqueado e em outros sistemas o mapa de memória se tornará inválido.

^Programar de maneira *lazy* significa adiar a inicialização de um objeto (neste caso, um data frame) até que ele seja exigido pelo usuário.

Para verificar a diferença de desemprenho no tempo de leitura entre as opções *lazy*, eu criei um benchmark no qual leio 100 vezes, com cada opção, o mesmo arquivo csv de 333 linhas. O resultado é o seguinte:

```r
library(microbenchmark)
library(tidyverse)

arquivo <- "~/Desktop/penguins.csv"

tempos <- 
    microbenchmark(
        "lazy_true" = {
            dados <- read_csv(arquivo, lazy = TRUE) # padrao da funcao
        },
        "lazy_false" = {
            dados <- read_csv(arquivo, lazy = FALSE)
        },
        times = 100)

autoplot(tempos)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Portanto, em algumas vezes utilizar `lazy = TRUE` (o padrão da função) é um pouco mais lento do que deixar `lazy = FALSE`, ao menos em arquivos com um número pequeno de linhas. Mesmo assim, esta diferença é imperceptível para o usuário, pois perceba que a unidade de tempo é milissegundos.

Ou seja, use `LAZY = FALSE` sempre que estiver trabalhando com arquivos csv pequenos e queira reescrevê-los com o mesmo nome e no mesmo diretório.